# Integration using rest api

Tags: rest-api, integration

We have an integration with third party application which consumes salesforce rest api. In between salesforce and application there is a security middleware. Rest api calls will pass through that middleware.We have created the URLs in the middleware to route the calls. When we make a call to get the access token using that url we get success, But when we try to call the actual service with that url and access token we get "Session expired or invalid session".

Answer (score 0):

Is the middleware directing the calls authenticated with the access token to the correct Salesforce pod?

The [response](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&language=en&type=0#send_up_response) from requesting the `access_token` will also include a `instance_url` that identifies the Salesforce pod/instance where the token is valid. You middleware would then need to direct subsequent calls to that URL.

Comment: Yes, At the first call to get the access token the middleware redirects to the salesforce and generates the access token.The issue I face with the second call when I try to hit the service with url and access token.

Comment: Can you successfully make the subsequent api call bypassing the middleware using the returned `access_token` and `instance_url`?

Comment: Using the instance url I am able to call the service,but not with the url from the middleware.

Comment: That would suggest to me that the middleware isn't sending the request to the correct URL. Beyond that it's hard to say what the problem is with access to the system making the actual API call.